# Why Firefox marks a image insecure but all requests in Network are secured

Tags: firefox, ssl, https

I am really curious, why Firefox marks this page insecure, and pointed out that one image is not loaded over ssl. Then I looked at the `Network` panel, it is clearly marked as secured, why is that?

See the screenshots

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the image is requested over HTTP, but gets a redirect response and then loads a different URL with HTTPS.

(I'd test it, but that's a ridiculous URL to transcribe. Please express as much of your question as *text* as possible. Pictures of text are not nice to work with.)

The first of those two requests is not secured.